# Converting a NULL instance of a class to a new empty class during mapping

Tags: automapper

I have the following automapper code:

```
CreateMap<JeffreysOnline.Data.BoothMaster, JeffreysOnline.Entities.BoothMaster>()
                .ForMember(s => s.RentClass, t => t.MapFrom(m => m.RentClass));
```

The BoothMaster class contains a class named RentClass. When the mapping occurs I'd like a new instance of RentClass assigned to BoothMaster when RentClass is NULL, instead of a NULL value assigned, as is occurring now when RentClass is NULL. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested the code but you should be able to do something like this:

```
CreateMap<JeffreysOnline.Data.BoothMaster, JeffreysOnline.Entities.BoothMaster>().BeforeMap((source, dest) =>
            {
                dest.RentClass = (source.RentClass == null) ? new RentClass(): source.RentClass;
            });
```